# Is there a way to bypass Excel's 2 minute Script runtime limit?

Tags: excel, timeout, office-scripts, microsoft365, time-limiting

I'm currently facing a challenge with an Excel script designed for processing a large dataset. Each time I attempt to run this script, I encounter a timeout error; "Range getCell: Timeout", see picture attached: [Timeout Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4U6S.png). This issue comes from the 2-minute execution limit for Excel scripts, which my script obviously exceeds since its a large dataset.

I've tried optimizing the script in many ways:

- Making it only run for specific sections, and repeating the process to cover the entire dataset. This requires a number of script executions, making my task tedious (and I mean A LOT of executions).
- Another thing I tried doing was changing the script itself to be more time efficient. But the dataset is simply way too large that this change is negligible and 2 minutes is nowhere near enough time to do what I need to do.

Given the constraints and my attempts at optimization, is there a way to bypass or extend this 2-minute limit?

## Edit

Here is the script;

```js
async function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook): Promise<void> {
  let table = workbook.getActiveWorksheet().getTables()[0];
  let dataBodyRange = table.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal();
  let tableValues = dataBodyRange.getValues();

  // Loop through each row of the table
  for (let i = 0; i < tableValues.length; i++) {
    // Process Dietary Restrictions
    let restrictions = tableValues[i][6] ? tableValues[i][6].toString() : "";
    processDietaryRestrictions(restrictions, dataBodyRange, i);

    // Process Hearing
    let hearing = tableValues[i][14] ? tableValues[i][14].toString() : "";
    processHearing(hearing, dataBodyRange, i);
  }

  console.log("Processed both Dietary Restrictions and Hearing columns.");
}

function processDietaryRestrictions(restrictionsString: string, dataBodyRange: ExcelScript.Range, rowIndex: number) {
  let parsedRestrictions = restrictionsString
    .replace(/^\["/, '')
    .replace(/"\]$/, '')
    .split('","')
    .map(s => s.trim())
    .map(s => s.replace(/^ \t/, ''));

  let dairyValue = parsedRestrictions.some(r => r.includes("Dairy") || r.includes("Produits laitiers")) ? "✔" : "";
  let peanutsValue = parsedRestrictions.some(r => r.includes("Peanuts") || r.includes("Cacahuètes")) ? "✔" : "";
  let eggsValue = parsedRestrictions.some(r => r.includes("Eggs") || r.includes("Œufs")) ? "✔" : "";
  let glutenValue = parsedRestrictions.some(r => r.includes("Gluten")) ? "✔" : "";
  let treeNutsValue = parsedRestrictions.some(r => r.includes("Tree nuts") || r.includes("Fruits à coque")) ? "✔" : "";
  let soyProductsValue = parsedRestrictions.some(r => r.includes("Soy products") || r.includes("Produits à base de soja")) ? "✔" : "";

  // For 'Other', find any entry that doesn't match known categories
  let otherEntries = parsedRestrictions.filter(r =>
    !r.includes("Dairy") && !r.includes("Produits laitiers") &&
    !r.includes("Peanuts") && !r.includes("Cacahuètes") &&
    !r.includes("Eggs") && !r.includes("Œufs") &&
    !r.includes("Gluten") &&
    !r.includes("Tree nuts") && !r.includes("Fruits à coque") &&
    !r.includes("Soy products") && !r.includes("Produits à base de soja")
  ).join(", ");
  let otherValue = otherEntries ? otherEntries : "";

  dataBodyRange.getCell(rowIndex, 7).setValues([[dairyValue]]);
  dataBodyRange.getCell(rowIndex, 8).setValues([[peanutsValue]]);
  dataBodyRange.getCell(rowIndex, 9).setValues([[eggsValue]]);
  dataBodyRange.getCell(rowIndex, 10).setValues([[glutenValue]]);
  dataBodyRange.getCell(rowIndex, 11).setValues([[treeNutsValue]]);
  dataBodyRange.getCell(rowIndex, 12).setValues([[soyProductsValue]]);
  dataBodyRange.getCell(rowIndex, 13).setValues([[otherValue]]);
}


function processHearing(hearingString: string, dataBodyRange: ExcelScript.Range, rowIndex: number) {
  if (hearingString.startsWith('[') && hearingString.endsWith(']')) {
    let cleanedHearingString = hearingString.replace(/'/g, '"');
    let parsedResponses: string[] = JSON.parse(cleanedHearingString);

    let ciponetValue = parsedResponses.includes("CIPOnet") || parsedResponses.includes("OPICnet") ? "✔" : "";
    let cipoinfoValue = parsedResponses.includes("CIPOinfo") || parsedResponses.includes("OPICinfo") ? "✔" : "";
    let colleagueValue = parsedResponses.includes("Colleague") ? "✔" : "";
    let managerValue = parsedResponses.includes("Manager") ? "✔" : "";
    let directorValue = parsedResponses.includes("Director") ? "✔" : "";
    let interConnexValue = parsedResponses.includes("InterConnex") ? "✔" : "";
    let cipoconnexValue = parsedResponses.includes("CIPOConnex") || parsedResponses.includes("OPICConnex") ? "✔" : "";

    // For 'Other2', find any entry that doesn't match known categories
    let otherEntries = parsedResponses.filter(r =>
      !r.includes("CIPOnet") && !r.includes("OPICnet") &&
      !r.includes("CIPOinfo") && !r.includes("OPICinfo") &&
      !r.includes("InterConnex") &&
      !r.includes("Colleague") &&
      !r.includes("Manager") &&
      !r.includes("Director") &&
      !r.includes("CIPOConnex") && !r.includes("OPICConnex")
    ).join(", ");
    let other2Value = otherEntries ? otherEntries : "";

    dataBodyRange.getCell(rowIndex, 15).setValues([[ciponetValue]]);
    dataBodyRange.getCell(rowIndex, 16).setValues([[cipoinfoValue]]);
    dataBodyRange.getCell(rowIndex, 17).setValues([[interConnexValue]]);
    dataBodyRange.getCell(rowIndex, 18).setValues([[cipoconnexValue]]);
    dataBodyRange.getCell(rowIndex, 19).setValues([[colleagueValue]]);
    dataBodyRange.getCell(rowIndex, 20).setValues([[managerValue]]);
    dataBodyRange.getCell(rowIndex, 21).setValues([[directorValue]]);
    dataBodyRange.getCell(rowIndex, 22).setValues([[other2Value]]);
  } else {
    console.log(`Row ${rowIndex + 1}: Invalid hearing string format`);
  }
}
```

The script takes the input from *Dietary Restriction* column and *Hearing* column and places check marks in the corresponding answer columns.

Example output:
**Hearing Column**

[image]

Comment: So show us your script. A bit hard to help without it. We may see ways to optimize it.

Comment: @Skin I added the script. If it can be optimized to reduce time to run that would be good, but preferably a way to bypass the 2 minute limit would be favorable (since that can be helpful for future scripts (and because i'm lazy to test repeatedly a newly made script for this task)).

Comment: FYI, I know of no way to avoid the two minute limit.  Chunking is always another option as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any way to overcome the two minute limit.

That being the case, I have two suggestions for you.

**Firstly**, if you find that the script is taking too long to run AND you're running it from PowerAutomate/LogicApps, I suggest chunking up the calls via a loop in PowerAutomate to only process a portion of the rows at once, i.e. 1 to 500, 501 to 1000, 1001 to 1500, etc.  It's a pain but it's a pattern that should work for you consistently.  You'd need to factor in the 1600 calls per day limit though.

**Secondly**, in relation to your script specifically, you could change blocks like this ...

```
dataBodyRange.getCell(rowIndex, 15).setValues([[ciponetValue]]);
dataBodyRange.getCell(rowIndex, 16).setValues([[cipoinfoValue]]);
dataBodyRange.getCell(rowIndex, 17).setValues([[interConnexValue]]);
dataBodyRange.getCell(rowIndex, 18).setValues([[cipoconnexValue]]);
dataBodyRange.getCell(rowIndex, 19).setValues([[colleagueValue]]);
dataBodyRange.getCell(rowIndex, 20).setValues([[managerValue]]);
dataBodyRange.getCell(rowIndex, 21).setValues([[directorValue]]);
dataBodyRange.getCell(rowIndex, 22).setValues([[other2Value]]);
```

... to be something like this ...

```
dataBodyRange.getRow(rowIndex).getUsedRange().setValues(
  [
    [null],
    [null],
    [null],
    [null],
    [null],
    [null],
    [null],
    [null],
    [null],
    [null],
    [null],
    [null],
    [null],
    [null],
    [ciponetValue], 
    [cipoinfoValue], 
    [interConnexValue], 
    [cipoconnexValue], 
    [colleagueValue], 
    [managerValue], 
    [directorValue], 
    [other2Value]
  ]
);
```

... and then reason for that is because calls back and forth to the worksheet/workbook use up large amounts of time.

When writing back, using `null` will make the value in the cell remain as is.  Given you only want to effect columns **15** to **22**, you'd need to do something like that unless you break down the range to do that, which is also possible and would look something like this ...

```
let updateRange = workbook.getActiveWorksheet().getRange(
  dataBodyRange.getCell(rowIndex, 15).getAddress() + ":" + 
  dataBodyRange.getCell(rowIndex, 22).getAddress());

updateRange.setValues([
  [ciponetValue],
  [cipoinfoValue],
  [interConnexValue],
  [cipoconnexValue],
  [colleagueValue],
  [managerValue],
  [directorValue],
  [other2Value]
]);
```

There are a few ways to skin this cat, but, the main concern is to reduce the amount of calls being made to the worksheet.